# Not able to create a file with a variable name using Filestream constructor (C#)

Tags: c#, filestream

I'm trying to create a file with a name which would take the "today" date as part of the name, by using the following syntax:

```
private static FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Test\log" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
```

It seems though that Filestream won't take a variable path... What would be a better approach to this?

Thx!

Comment: Do you get an error? What makes you think that it can't take a variable path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you generating a path with embedded slashes, which `ToShortDateString()` returns for the `en-US` culture.  In your example, it is trying to open a file `C:\Test\log12/6/2010.txt`, and I imagine that the folder `C:\Test\log12\6` does not exist.

Try using something like `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` to datestamp your files instead.

Answer (score 1):

HI Aidenn,

The prolem isn't file stream.   It is how you are creating the file name.  If you put the file name in a variable, you can see it.  Here is what it looks like:

"C:\Test\log12/5/2010.txt"

See how the method ToShortDateString()  includes the '/' character?  Those are valid directory separators.   So, the lower level Win32 call to CreateFile() fails since the direcory "log12" and "5" cannot be found.

You need to create a file name tha doesn't contain any invalid file name characters.

See this article [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx)  on MSDN.

-foredecker